# Subquery using derived table in Hibernate HQL

Tags: hql, derived

I have a Hibernate HQL question.
I'd like to write a subquery as a derived table (for performance reasons).
Is it possible to do that in HQL?
Example:

```
FROM Customer WHERE country.id in 
(SELECT id FROM (SELECT id FROM Country where type='GREEN') derivedTable)
```

(btw, this is just a sample query so don't give advice on rewriting it, is just the derived table concept I'm interested in)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately no, derived tables don't currently work in HQL.
For example, the following works:

```
List<int> result =
  nHSession.CreateQuery( @"select distinct Id from User u")
  .List<int>().ToList();
```

...the following throws the this exception:
***Exception of type 'Antlr.Runtime.NoViableAltException' was thrown. near line 1,
column 24 [select distinct Id from (select u from S2.BP.Model.User u)]***

```
List<int> result = nHSession.CreateQuery(
    @"select distinct Id from (select u from User u)")
    .List<int>().ToList();
```

The fall back would be to create a named query containing raw sql or to create a stored procedure and invoke it via named query, like so:

```
List<int> result = nHSession.GetNamedQuery("spUserIds")
    .SetInt32("id", 3)
    .List<int>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find some information about derived properties and performance considerations on my blog in http://blog.eyallupu.com/2009/07/hibernate-derived-properties.html

Hope it will help,
Eyal Lupu

Comment: Interesting article, but not really pertaining to the question.