# hibernate - How to get select within a select using Criteria

Tags: mysql, hibernate, sql-order-by, hibernate-criteria

I have the following mysql statement `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM NINJA  ORDER BY NAME LIMIT 0,5) AS TABLE ORDER BY NAME DESC`. I don't know how am I gonna convert it into hibernate criteria. The reason Im doing this kind of select statement is to get the first 5 result then order it descending. In my current criteria in which Im doing the normal `Order.addOrder(Order.desc(field))` what happens is it gets the last 5 result of the whole record.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

Below are some of my codes :

```
Criteria ninjaCriteria = session.createCriteria(Ninja.class);
ninjaCriteria.setFirstResult(firstResult);
ninjaCriteria.setMaxResults(maxResult);
if (isAscending)
    ninjaCriteria.addOrder(Order.asc(field));
else
    ninjaCriteria.addOrder(Order.desc(field));
```

Note: `firstResult`, `maxResult`, `isAscending`, and `field`  are variables.

Comment: Even with HQL derived table is not possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433729/subquery-using-derived-table-in-hibernate-hql, and with criteria query you can go as far as sub-query with DetachedCriteria and another restriction is that DetachedCriteria does not have setMaxResult

Answer (score 3):

Try this one. i hope it will work

```
Criteria ninjaCriteria = session.createCriteria(Ninja.class);
 ninjaCriteria.addOrder(Order.desc("NAME"));
ninjaCriteria.setMaxResults(5);
```

Comment: This will get the last five sorted in descending order. The OP wants the _first_ five sorted in descending order.

Answer (score 2):

The only way how you can solve this without using pure SQL, for my opinion, is to select the list of `Ninja`s as usual:

```
Criteria ninjaCriteria = session.createCriteria(Ninja.class);
ninjaCriteria.addOrder(Order.asc("NAME"));
ninjaCriteria.setMaxResults(5);
```

create a custom `Comparator`:

```
/**
 * Compare Ninjas by Name descending
 */
private static Comparator<Ninja> ninjaNameComparator = new Comparator<Ninja>() {
    public int compare(Ninja ninja1, Ninja ninja2) {
        return ninja2.getName().compareTo(ninja1.getName());
    }
};
```

and use it to sort that list descending:

```
Collection<Ninja> ninjas = ninjaDao.listNinja();
Collections.sort(ninjas, ninjaNameComparator);
```

From bussiness point of view it's absolutely identical and do not required hard solutions.